Alternative method to deriving autocorrelation function of stationary AR(2) process
I have read this question/answer:
Autocorrelation of a stationary AR(2) process
How can we derive this using Expectation.
Let $Y_t = \phi_0 +\phi_1 Y_{t-1} + \phi_2 Y_{t-2}+\epsilon_t$
I found the mean:
$\mu = E(Y_t)= \phi_1 E(Y_{t-1})+\phi_2E(Y_{t-2})$
Then using this property:
$cov[Y_t, Y_{t-2}] = E[(Y_t-\mu)(Y_{t-2}-\mu)]$
How can we use this to derive that in the link?
$cov[Y_t, Y_{t-2}] = E[(Y_t-\phi_1 E(Y_{t-1})+\phi_2E(Y_{t-2}))(Y_{t-2}-\phi_1 E(Y_{t-1})+\phi_2E(Y_{t-2}))]$
I am stuck here.
How do I get to this -
$$
\begin{align}
= \phi_{1}\ \rho_{k-1} + \phi_{2}\ \rho_{k-2}\\
\end{align}
$$

Your method is no different than the one explained in your reference -- it's just more cumbersome.  Please use the bilinearity property to streamline your calculations.
